# Use authenticated urls for gcs only without setting "console.cloud.google.com" referer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I hope someone can help me with figuring out how to use authenticated URLs with gcs.

---

**What I am trying to archive:**

1. I want to send someone an authenticated gcs link (not pre-signed): e.g. https://storage.cloud.google.com/XXX/happy-simon.png
2. That person needs to log into their Google account
3. If they have the proper rights, they can download the file

---

**Problem:**

Whem I try to access an authenticated URL for GCS they do not work in the browser, but  only when the Header "referer: [https://console.cloud.google.com/"](https://console.cloud.google.com/%22) is set.

---

**How to reproduce:**

1. Upload a file to gcs
2. Give yourself at least read privileges on that file (you should be owner anyways as you uploaded it)
3. Try to download it via the "Authenticated Url"
   [image]

3.1) When I click on the link in the google cloud console the download works without problems

3.2) When I copy the url and open it in a new tab I get a 403 error

Testing with curl on the console I found out that the difference between the two calls is wether the `-H 'referer: https://console.cloud.google.com/'` is set or not. If I set it, also the call from the new tab works.

Comment: 403 should be expected if you are trying to download the file with an account without rights to download it. Have you tested using the link on an incognito window and then authenticating? If you are using the same permissions as in the console, it should work.

Comment: @rsalinas Yes, I tried it via incognito and signing in. The same account that can download from the cloud console via link click gets a 403 in the incognito window :/

Comment: I have been testing this and as you mention this seems to be an issue. I would recommend you raising an it to the [GCP issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1162869) in order for google to be able to work on this

Comment: Looks like you only can access that issue tracker if you are an google employee (or at least have an @google.com email address)

Comment: It would appear that this is by design when Data Access audit logs are enabled. [Support Case](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/unexpected-error-message-403-forbidden-error-when-copy-pasting-the-storage-object-using-its-storage-cloud-google-com-url-whereas-direct-clicking-on-the-same-url-open-through-authenticated-url-000007217), [Enable Data Access audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#before-you-begin)

Comment: You are looking for `cookie-based authentication`: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#cookieauth I have not implemented that form, so I do know the details. Hopefully, that term will help you search for more information.

Comment: A few details I know. The Google authentication creates a cookie stored in the browser. When you go to `https://storage.cloud.google.com/BUCKET/OBJECT`, Cloud Storage processes that cookie and generates a signature, and redirects you to a URL (maybe a form of signed URL?) at `googleusercontent.com`.

Comment: This link has better details. Turns out the URL includes an Identity Token obfuscated in some way: https://download.huihoo.com/google/gdgdevkit/DVD1/developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication.html#cookieauth